# Delete all lines containing multiple strings using sed

Tags: regex, bash, unix, awk, sed

I have two files. I want delete all strings(in url.txt) from log.txt

First file is url.txt

```
google.com
bing.com
yahoo.com
```

Second file is log.txt

```
   1.2.3 www.google.com bot
   626.7.7 www.yahoo.com browser
   35.5.6 www.test.com  search
   44.6.6 www.bing.com  web
```

I want this output:

```
35.5.6 www.test.com  search
```

this code works for a string but I want delete all strings(in url.txt) from log.txt

```
sed -i '/$string/d' log.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk 'NR==FNR{urls["www."$1]; next} !($2 in urls)' url.txt log.txt
```

The above will ONLY match on the specific URL in the specific desired field of log.txt

Answer (score 6):

You can use this `grep -v`:

```
grep -vwFf url.txt log.txt
35.5.6 www.test.com  search
```

Comment: That will incorrectly delete longer URLs if present, e.g. if log.txt contained `44.6.6 www.stabbing.com  web` that would match against `bing.com`. You need to add the `-w` arg for grep. That still leaves you with the problem that it'd falsely delete a line like `44.6.6 www.stabbing.com  glad this is not bing.com` since it's not matching on any specific field but that may not be an issue.

Comment: understand your point but it is not say that stabbing.com is to be kept. he say "all string" not limited to root domain. And a `bing.com.phising.to` is (maybe hopefully) removed (but you keep both your +1 ;-D )

Answer (score 0):

Extending your `sed` script, here is extended script to parse through each line in url.txt and delete the correspoding string in log.txt

```
while read string
do
    sed -i '/$string/d' log.txt
done < url.txt
```